# Pandas DataFrame slicing with iteration

Tags: python, pandas, loops, slice

I would like to perform some action on sliced DataFrame with multiple slice indexes. The pattern is df.iloc[0:24] , df.iloc[24:48], df.iloc[48:72] and so on with step 24 as you get it. How I can iterate it without to set it manually every time. More like df.iloc[x:z] and each iteration x=0, z=24 and next iteration with 24 step, x will be 24 and z=48 and so on.
Thanks in advance,
Hristo.

Comment: `df.iloc[::24]` This is a _very_ basic indexing problem, you really should look up slice notation.

Comment: No,no. mate I don't have a problem with slicing. But I need specific dataframe slice parts from 0-24 and perform some operations, then df[24:48] and perform some operation with that sliced part so I need to iterate each sliced DF and perform some actions.

Comment: Ah, alright. Apologies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### `for` <sub>loop iteration</sub>

```
for i in range(0, len(df), 24):
    slc = df.iloc[i : i + 24]
```

---

#### `groupby`

```
df.groupby(df.index // 24 * 24).apply(your_function)
```

Comment: + 1 for the for loop, just want to make a note: ‘slc’ is the sliced dataframe that jnclude the iterations, so all operations are performed to the ‘slc’

Answer (score 1):

output it will give df with

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
  dfnew = df.iloc[i : i + 42]
  i = i + 1
  print(dfnew)
```

0 to 41 indices data
1 to 42
2 to 43
by skipping first entire row with limit 42 rows of data.

Comment: Even though this wasn't the solution OP needed, I for sure did, thank you.